# Renaming files in wget2

Tags: batch, wget

I am batch downloading images from links saved  in text files. How I can rename files(adding prefix or completely new name) on the go as file gets downloaded to maintain order as  images don't have any exif data to sort by date newer/older.

```
$ for f in *.txt; do wget2 max-threads=3 --tries=2 --timeout=90 -i "$f" -P "${f%.txt}"; done
```

I can do this with curl script, but limitation is one by one file download, takes triple time to download files, un-utilising bandwidth.

Comment: Check out the `-O` switch for `wget`.

Comment: Hi, Beginner here, I used -P argument to create directory. How I can use -0 in above?

Comment: Not  `-0`, `-O`. Check the `man` page. `-O` allows you to redirect the download to a different file, effectively renaming it to what you want.